# I can't build apk flutter app. Error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, build, apk, flutter-android

I wanted to test my flutter app in phone. So i tried build an apk. I ran this in app files:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

results:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Can Ahmet\StudioProjects\myapp\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not open cp_dsl generic class cache for script 'C:\SRC\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' (C:\Users\Can Ahmet\.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\926y60l3pifaoznpot8d19f2t).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           17,5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

How can i solve that?

I tried run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace.
result:

```
Could not find an option named "stacktrace".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

I tried run with `--debug` option to get more log output.
result:

```
'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Did i wrong write?

[image: Run images]

Comment: Try to reinstall flutter and do share your flutter version

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `flutter build apk --release` (for release build apk)

   `flutter build apk --debug` (for debug apk)

Still, if the problem is not resolved try with a lower version of `Gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

I had Java 19 and gradle 6.7. Those are not compatible. You can learn Compatibility Matrix [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

I used java 19 and gradle 7.6. Those are compatible. That is worked. But now i have new problem [Flutter Error (while build apk) : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74906105/flutter-error-while-build-apk-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-cou)